# Modular route design in Angular Dart to support independently developed feature sets?

Tags: dart, angular-routing, angular-dart

[*Updated* to focus question]. AngularDart nicely supports **modular app design** in many respects. Is this also the case for **route design**? I.e.,

**Question: Can an app have more than one `RouteInitializer`?** E.g., would the following be possible:

```dart
class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() { ...
    type(RouteInitializer, 
       // Currently implementedBy takes only one RouteInitializer? 
       // Here we propose, e.g., to allow a list.
       implementedBy: 
         [MyAppRouteInitializerForFeatureSetA,
         MyAppRouteInitializerForFeatureSetB,
         MyAppRouteInitializerForFeatureSetC,
         ]);
    ...
  }
}
```

**Use case**: I am considering asking some of my students to work on the same AngularDart project, but on (mostly) mutually exclusive feature sets. Ideally I would like for them to work independently (once a "top-level" route URL prefixes are agreed upon). In such a case they would end up having their own `RouteInitializer`s. It would be nice to be able to just "drop" in their project subfolders, come integration time, rather than copy-pasting route initialization into a single class file.

---

[Original version of question] (Given that the interface name is `RouteInitializer`, rather than possibly `RouterInitializer`, gives the impression more than one can be defined.)

1. Is this also the case for **route design**? I.e.,
2. How many `Router` instances can be associated to an Angular Dart app? (I suppose only one.)
3. Can an app have more than one `RouteInitializer`? (Given that the interface name is `RouteInitializer`, rather than possibly `RouterInitializer`, gives the impression more than one can be defined.
4. If more than one `RouteInitializer` is permitted, then what is the scope of the `addRoute` `name` parameter?

Edit: actually the last question has merit of its own in the context of hierarchical routes, so I factored it out to here: [angulardart-namespace-of-route-names-hierarchical-too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462588/angulardart-namespace-of-route-names-hierarchical-too).

Comment: What's the usecase? Why would you need multiple routers?

Comment: @pavelgj, in case you had not seen it, I added a description of a use case to the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple `RouteInitializer`s is complicated, as you pointed out.

Technically you don't needs help form angular do achieve this.

**my_routes.dart**

```dart
import 'foo.dart' as foo;
import 'bar.dart' as bar;

myRouteInitializer(router, views) {
  views.configure({
    'foo': foo.configureFooRoutes(),
    'bar': bar.configureBarRoutes()
  });
}
```

**foo.dart**

```dart
library foo;

import '';

configureFooRoutes(views) => ngRoute(
    path: '/foo',
    mount: ...);
```

**bar.dart**

```dart
library bar;

import '';

configureBarRoutes(views) => ngRoute(
    path: '/bar',
    mount: ...);
```

This way your students can work independently.