# AngularDart routing where parameter contains slashes

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm new to both Angular and Dart, and I'm writing an app which has categories that are hierarchical.  This is represented by their IDs being a slash-deliminated list of the path to that category (including its parents) - in other words, 'category-1' for top-level category, 'category-1/category-2' for a child, 'category-1/category-2/category-3' for a grandchild.

I'd like my URL scheme to reflect this hierarchy (ie for category-2, '#categories/category-1/category-2').

This is my current RouteInitializerFn (I'm then pulling out the 'categoryId' parameter in the controller for 'categories'):

```dart
void routeInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) {
  views.configure({
    'subcategories' : ngRoute(
        path: 'categories/:categoryId',
        viewHtml: '<categories></categories>',
    ),
    'categories': ngRoute(
        path: 'categories',
        viewHtml: '<categories></categories>',
    ),
  });
}
```

This appears to trip up on the slashes, though; the value of 'categoryId' for URL '#categories/category-1/category-2' is 'category-1'.

The AngularJS docs suggest this is possible in JS land (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider - the docs for the 'path' parameter); I've tried changing my path to various permutations of what's there without any luck, nor can I find anything relevant in the issue tracker.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

OK, think I've figured this out. The culprit is https://github.com/angular/route.dart/blob/master/lib/url_template.dart#L6 - specifically, the regex which matches the value of a parameter is 'any character except the start of a string or /' at least once. I think the fix is to change that regex to be r'\?(.+)' (all the old unit tests still pass, as do the new ones I hacked up).

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a temporary workaround. You can't swap in a different implementation of UrlMatcher because the use of UrlTemplate is baked into the ngRoute method; if one were to change NgRouteCfg's 'path' parameter to be a dynamic type and assert it was either a String or a UrlMatcher (which is what the innards of route_hierarchical does, so you could pass it straight through) that would also be a reasonable solution, but for the moment it looks like the path forward is to fix in head.

Comment: This question shows an example how to do hierarchical routing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462588

Comment: That doesn't handle the case of the parameter itself containing a slash, though, which is what I need here.

Comment: Seems support for this has landed https://github.com/angular/route.dart/pull/55

Answer (score 1):

The Angular-Dart tutorial has a few infos too

see:

- https://angulardart.org/tutorial/08-ch06-view.html
- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_06/lib/routing/recipe_book_router.dart

> The mount parameter allows you to define nested routes.

```dart
void recipeBookRouteInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) {
  views.configure({
    'add': ngRoute(
        path: '/add',
        view: 'view/addRecipe.html'),
    'recipe': ngRoute(
        path: '/recipe/:recipeId',
        mount: {
          'view': ngRoute(
              path: '/view',
              view: 'view/viewRecipe.html'),
          'edit': ngRoute(
              path: '/edit',
              view: 'view/editRecipe.html'),
          'view_default': ngRoute(
              defaultRoute: true,
              enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) =>
                  router.go('view', {},
                      startingFrom: router.root.findRoute('recipe'),
                      replace: true))
        })
  });
}
```